# modifying output directory in outbound-channel-adapter spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

The following is my configuration xml for a file polling functionality. I have to change the output directory sometimes.

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn" directory="file:${paths.root}" channel="abc" >
        <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="5000"/>

    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
    <int:channel id="abc"/>

    <int-file:outbound-channel-adapter channel="abc" id="filesOut" 
    directory-expression="@aPath.getPath()"
    delete-source-files="true" 
    filename-generator ="filenameGenerator"/>

<bean id="filenameGenerator" class="com.dms.util.FileNameGenerator"/>
```

In the

```
 @Override
    public String generateFileName(Message<?> message)
    {
```

I have tried setting the value of a configured bean property.
This is the additional configuration for that

```
<bean name="aPath" class="com.dms.util.GetOutPath">
    <property name="path" value="${paths.destination}"/>
</bean>
```

paths.destination is from a property file.
In the generateFileName method I have added the code for changing the property value as follows

```
@Autowired
    private GetOutPath outPathBean;
```

For the bean:

```
@Component("outPathBean")
```

and in my code

```
outPathBean.setPath(newFolder);
```

My debugging shows that the value of the property does not change. My question is, How do I modify the directory either in the generateFileName method or by any other way.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general mechanism you are trying to use will work because the file name generator is calle before evaluating the directory expression.

However, you have two instances of you really have the `@Component` defined (and you are using component scanning, you will have two instances of `GetOutPath` - `aPath` and `outPathBean`.

The expression is using the instance that you are not changing.

You need to inject the same bean instance that you are using in your expression.

Comment: Thanks.  So if I remove the config file bean declaration, this should work? ?

Comment: OK done!! removed the xml declaration and worked like a charm. Will the same happen if i remove the @component and leave the xml declaration? I am not sure if I will have access to the bean in Filenamegenerator .. Thanks

Comment: Yes. Removing either one will work. With only one bean you won't even have to change the bean name.